# SUM of total per month

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this table with two columns:

```
Price       Date
45.00       12/06/2015 12:32:54 AM
455.98      22/06/2015 11:00:32 AM
32.00       08/07/2015 09:11:45 AM
98.00       11/07/2015 19:22:32 PM
```

**(the date is in the format DD/MM/YYYY)**

I need to get the sum of prices grouped by month and for this I need to find a code in sqlite that cut some parts of that date only getting the month (...06...)(...07...). Below is my code used for some parts of the SELECT:

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(price as INTEGER)) as TOTALPERMONTH FROM cart_history GROUP BY ....... ORDER BY ID
```

How I can grouped by some parts of that row?

Comment: Why are you using that date format? Can't you change it?

Answer (score -1):

Use [`STRFTIME`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) function

```
select SUM(CAST(price as INTEGER)) as  Total, 
       strftime('%m', dateField) as Month
From yourtable
Group by strftime('%m', dateField)
```

Comment: My column date is varchar, not datetime, have a problem?

Answer (score -1):

use `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(price as INTEGER)) as TOTALPERMONTH 
FROM cart_history,Date
GROUP BY Date
HAVING Date IN('your dates ')'
```